# Python-Shell / Node JS output empty

Tags: python, node.js, npm, electron

Backstory: I'm creating an application using Electron and am currently attempting to run a function when the computer is locked/unlocked.

After much trial and error I finally managed to get the following python code working. The code prints either Locked or Unlocked on the screen when the relevant codes are fired. I now need to run the python script from Node JS so that I can run more functions when the events fire.

```
import win32con
import win32gui
import win32ts
import time

print("Test")

WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE        = 0x2B1class WTSMonitor():
className = "WTSMonitor"
wndName = "WTS Event Monitor"

def __init__(self):
    wc = win32gui.WNDCLASS()
    wc.hInstance = hInst = win32gui.GetModuleHandle(None)
    wc.lpszClassName = self.className
    wc.lpfnWndProc = self.WndProc
    self.classAtom = win32gui.RegisterClass(wc)

    style = 0
    self.hWnd = win32gui.CreateWindow(self.classAtom, self.wndName,
        style, 0, 0, win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT, win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT,
        0, 0, hInst, None)
    win32gui.UpdateWindow(self.hWnd)
    win32ts.WTSRegisterSessionNotification(self.hWnd, win32ts.NOTIFY_FOR_ALL_SESSIONS)

def start(self):
    win32gui.PumpMessages()

def stop(self):
    win32gui.PostQuitMessage(0)

def WndProc(self, hWnd, message, wParam, lParam):
    if message == WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE:
        self.OnSession(wParam, lParam)

def OnSession(self, event, sessionID):
    if event == 7:
        print("Locked")
    if event == 8:
        print("Unlocked")
    print(event)
    myststa(event)
WTSMonitor().start()
```

The Node code:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
let py = spawn('python',['locked.py'])
py.stdout.on('data', data => console.log('data : ', data.toString()))
py.on('close', ()=>{
})
```

When I run python from the console using "Python locked.py" I see the test message printed. However, when running using node locked.js the script looks like it's running but never prints to the console.

The other thing to mention is that if I comment out the final line WTSMonitor().start() then I can see the test message print to the node console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before getting down actual troubleshooting, what's main reason to use python to invoke w32api? First you can do it via electron / nodejs itself, moreover electron will have a specific event in powerMonitor directly (https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/3a0640993ba9748ced9f9cd00de5dbfe7651f788/docs/api/power-monitor.md#event-lock-screen-macos-windows) doesn't necessarily need 3rd party codes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I was using the documents on the main page here: https://electronjs.org/docs/all#powermonitor which doesn't list the lock-screen event. I've updated both NPM and electron and attempted to use the following within the app.on('ready') function:
electron.powerMonitor.on('suspend', () => {
    console.log('The system is going to sleep')
  })

However, it doesn't output anything to the console :(

Thanks for the reply!

Comment: note I mentioned `electron will have` - it's not exposed current latest version.